# Given $I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^ne^{\sqrt{x}}dx$ find $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I need some guidance regarding the following problem, given the integral:

$$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^ne^{\sqrt{x}}dx$$ where $n=0,1,2,...$

I have to find: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}I_{n}$$

Comment: $I_n$ does not depend on $x$. Maybe you wanted $\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} I_n$?

Comment: @user122673, Integrate by parts to form a Recurrence relation

Comment: @Crostul yes, fixed it, i tried parts to find a link between the $I_{n}$ to express it recursively

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can evaluate the integral directly using elementary techniques including induction, but we can do a little better with the observation that as $n \to \infty$ the value of the integrand is very small on almost the entire integral, and so we might expect it goes to $0$ in the limit. A standard technique in this situation is to bound the integrand above and below by functions easier to integrate.

The interval $[0, 1]$, $0 \leq e^{\sqrt{x}} \leq e$, so $$0 \leq x^n e^{\sqrt{x}} \leq e x^n,$$ and thus
$$0 \leq I_n \leq \int_0^1 e x^n \,dx = \frac{e}{n + 1}.$$

By the Squeeze Theorem, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

For all $n \geq 1$ you have
$$0 \leq I_n = \int_0^1 x^n e^{\sqrt{x}} dx \leq \int_0^1 x^n e^{\sqrt{1}} dx 
=e \int_0^1 x^n dx = \frac{e}{n+1}$$

So by the sandwich theorem
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} I_n = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the dominated convergence theorem. Over $I=(0,1)$, $x^n\,e^{\sqrt{x}}$ is positive and bounded by $e$; since the sequence given by $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges pointwise to zero in I, the limit of $I_n$ when $n$ approches $+\infty$ is zero.

As an alternative, by convexity we have:
$$I_n = 2\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+1}\,e^x\,dx\leq 2\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+1}(1+(e-1)x)\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{2e-2}{2n+3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\
f(x) = x^n e^{\sqrt x } 
\
$ and $\
I_n  = \int\limits_0^1 {x^n e^{\sqrt x } } 
\
$. Let us apply the Mean Value Theorem on $I_n$. This operation yields $\
I_n  = \int\limits_0^1 {x^n e^{\sqrt x } }  = (1 - 0)f(\xi ) = \xi ^n e^{\sqrt \xi  } ,\xi  \in (0,1)
\
$ . It should now be obvious that as $\
n \to \infty ,I_n  \to 0
\
$ .